# How to Show two bottomSheets in Android using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to display two bottom sheets at the bottom of the screen using BottomSheetScaffold in jetpack compose. One sheet is small height(20.dp) and other sheet is more height(200.dp)

But it shows only one sheet at the bottom other sheet is not showing. I am using below code to display two bottom sheets.

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    BottomSheetOne()
    BottomSheetTwo()
}

@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun BottomSheetOne() {
    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Expanded)
    )
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
             Column(
                  Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                        .background(Color(0xAA3fa7cc))
             ) {
              Text(
                   modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp, 5.dp, 16.dp, 15.dp),
                   color = Color.White,
                   text = "Name",
              )
             }
        },
        sheetPeekHeight = 20.dp
    ) {

    }
}

@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun BottomSheetTwo() {
    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed)
    )
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
             Column(
                  Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                        .background(Color(0xAA3fa7cc))
             ) {
              Text(
                   modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp, 5.dp, 16.dp, 15.dp),
                   color = Color.White,
                   text = "Name",
              )
             }
        },
        sheetPeekHeight = 200.dp
    ) {

    }
}
```